# why mathtools does not work for showing only equations which are referred to in the text?

Tags: equations, mathtools

I am using [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) in the following way:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
```

Then, to refer to equations I use `\refeq{equation}`.

What happens is that there is a numbering for the equation that appears in the text, but the (Eq-Number) does not appear next to the equation itself. In fact, there are no (Eq-Number) for any of the equations.

Any ideas what could cause that? Is there a way to force to have an equation number next to an equation?

**Edit**

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsfonts,eucal,amsbsy,amsthm,amsopn,amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}



\begin{document}


\begin{eqnarray}
A & = & B \label{eq:first}
\end{eqnarray}

see Equation ~\refeq{eq:first}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you define your equations? You *should* wrap them in `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` (or `\begin{eqnarray} ... \end{eqnarray}` depending if you have one or more rows you want to number...) - maybe you're just wrapping them in `\[ \]` or something?

Comment: @Tomas: No `eqnarray`, please :-)

Comment: A [complete minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) might be useful.

Comment: According to `mathtools`'s manual, you are supposed to use `\eqref{..}` and not `\refeq{..}` \\
Beside this, the equation numbering is reintroduced not directly after inserting the \ref, but after two or sometimes three compilations. \\
For the question "Is there a way to force to have an equation number next to an equation?" : yes, you can use `\tag{something}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in your example that you are using `eqnarray`. This is well-known to be seriously defective, and a number of tools simply do not support it. I see that `eqnarray` does not show up in the `mathtools` manual, so I suspect the omission may not be accidental! Use the `gather` or `align` environments, as shown in the `mathtools` manual.

For more detail on the problems of `eqnarray` see the [UK FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray).

Comment: Works now. But I used with eqnarray \lefteqn in quite many places, so that I have more space for the line below the first line. It does work well with the align environment. Any replacement? Thanks.